# date of street view static image

Tags: google-street-view

I am using Google's Street View Static Image API. It works great, but I am wondering if it is possible to get meta data for the images I am saving, specifically the date. Is there anyway to know the date of the static image?

Thanks,
Lee

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the image date using the [Google Maps Street View Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) in JavaScript.

Briefly, you would need to [go through the usual setup steps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to get Google Maps working on your page, then you would do something akin to:

```
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
var berkeley = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085,-122.254775);
sv.getPanoramaByLocation(berkeley, 50, function(data) {
    console.log(data.imageDate);
});
```

**data.imageDate** will contain the date in *YYYY-MM* format.

You can use StreetViewService's both *getPanoramaById* and *getPanoramaByLocation* methods to obtain this data. Please [see here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewService).

Answer (score 0):

var panoramaOptions = {
                        position: streetViewLocation,
                        pov: {
                            heading: 0,
                            pitch: 5,
                            zoom: 1
                        },
                        visible: true,
                        addressControl: false,
                        **imageDateControl:true**
                    };

Comment: For me this appears to have no effect, though other options work as advertised.

Comment: At first I saw no effect. But the date is there, in tiny print next to the copyright notice at the bottom of the image.